# GetFiles exclude a string

Tags: c#, getfiles, directoryinfo

with the following code I am able to get all files that includes a `string` in their name:

```
DirectoryInfo dirInf = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] fInfArray = dirInf.GetFiles("*string*");
```

But **how do I exclude a string at `GetFiles`**.
I dont mean the ending like `.txt` I want to exclude a `string` in the name of the file.

For example I have the following files:

```
wordwordfile.msg  
wordwordfile.txt  
wodfile.txt
```

and exclude wod to get the following files:

```
wordwordfile.msg  
wordwordfile.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\")
                .EnumerateFiles("*string*")
                .Where(f => !f.Name.Contains("wod"))
                // Optional, convert to array if you want
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: Change `GetFiles()` to `EnumerateFiles()` and get rid of the pointless `ToList()`.

Comment: Good shout - wasn't aware of that method.

Comment: wait.. the list still contains "wod" :(

Comment: Can you post your implementation? Is a case issue?

Comment: Maybe try `!f.Name.ToLower().Contains`

Comment: i litteraly took your answer and filled in my exclude:
`var files = new DirectoryInfo(path).EnumerateFiles().Where(f => !f.Name.Contains("*wod*"));`
the count of the list is still the same as before

Comment: You don't need the `*` around wod. `Contains()` doesn't require wildcards.

Comment: thats so embarrasing... but even without the `*` the list still contains wod

Comment: ok, wow i dont know why, but i just closed and restarted my application and now it works. thx for the time u spend to help me